# ASP.NET razor Html.TextArea

Tags: asp.net, textarea, html-helper

1)
while editing a view with the row:

```
    @Html.TextArea(name: "Message", rows: 10, columns: 40)
```

I'm getting this error at compile time:

```
ERR: "The best overload for 'TextArea' does not have a parameter of type 'rows'"
```

even if there's a signature with rows and columns as parameters.

2)
So I try with the signature:
        @Html.TextArea(string name, object htmlAttributes)

invoking the function as follows

```
    @Html.TextArea(name: "Message", new { rows=10, columns=40 }
```

but I'm getting another error:

```
ERR: "Named Argument Specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified"
```

Anyone knows why and how to solve them?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just change the code to:

```
@Html.TextArea("Message", new { rows=10, columns=40 })
```

without the named parameter

Comment: Perfect that was the problem of the second issue. While for the first one it's necessary to specify all the tags of the signature: Html.TextArea(name:"Message", rows: 10, columns: 40, value:"", htmlAttributes: new {})

Comment: Seems like "columns" isn't working, but "cols" is. So if you have the same problem like me, try this.

Answer (score 11):

ave you tried removing the name tag off of the name parameter?

```
@Html.TextArea("Message", new { rows = 10, cols = 40})
```

Also, the HTML attribute for the columns on a `textarea` is `cols` not `columns`

Comment: It's ok without the tag. Both cols and columns are ok to set the attribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add it as an attribute like so...

```
@Html.TextArea("Message", new { rows=10, columns=40 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { cols = 35, @rows = 3 })
```